# Pythonic way to parse command line output into a container object

Tags: python, parsing, object, dictionary, properties

Please read this whole question before answering, as it's not what you think...  I'm looking at creating python object wrappers that represent hardware devices on a system (trimmed example below).

```
class TPM(object):

    @property
    def attr1(self):
        """
        Protects value from being accidentally modified after 
        constructor is called.
        """
        return self._attr1

    def __init__(self, attr1, ...):
        self._attr1 = attr1
        ...

    @classmethod
    def scan(cls):
        """Calls Popen, parses to dict, and passes **dict to constructor"""
```

Most of the constructor inputs involve running command line outputs in subprocess.Popen and then parsing the output to fill in object attributes.  I've come up with a few ways to handle these, but I'm unsatisfied with what I've put together just far and am trying to find a better solution.  Here are the common catches that I've found.  (Quick note: tool versions are tightly controlled, so parsed outputs don't change unexpectedly.)

1. Many tools produce variant outputs, sometimes including fields and sometimes not.  This means that if you assemble a dict to be wrapped in a container object, the constructor is more or less forced to take **kwargs and not really have defined fields.  I don't like this because it makes static analysis via pylint, etc less than useful.  I'd prefer a defined interface so that sphinx documentation is clearer and errors can be more reliably detected.
2. In lieu of **kwargs, I've also tried setting default args to None for many of the fields, with what ends up as pretty ugly results.  One thing I dislike strongly about this option is that optional fields don't always come at the end of the command line tool output.  This makes it a little mind-bending to look at the constructor and match it up to tool output.
3. I'd greatly prefer to avoid constructing a dictionary in the first place, but using setattr to create attributes will make pylint unable to detect the _attr1, etc... and create warnings.  Any ideas here are welcome...

Basically, I am looking for the proper Pythonic way to do this.  My requirements, for a re-summary are the following:

1. Command line tool output parsed into a container object.
2. Container object protects attributes via properties post-construction.
3. Varying number of inputs to constructor, with working static analysis and error detection for missing required fields during runtime.

Is there a good way of doing this (hopefully without a ton of boilerplate code) in Python?  If so, what is it?

---

EDIT:

Per some of the clarification requests, we can take a look at the tpm_version command.  Here's the output for my laptop, but for this TPM it doesn't include every possible attribute.  Sometimes, the command will return extra attributes that I also want to capture.  This makes parsing to known attribute names on a container object fairly difficult.

```
TPM 1.2 Version Info:
Chip Version:        1.2.4.40
Spec Level:          2
Errata Revision:     3
TPM Vendor ID:       IFX
Vendor Specific data: 04280077 0074706d 3631ffff ff
TPM Version:         01010000
Manufacturer Info:   49465800
```

Example code (ignore lack of sanity checks, please.  trimmed for brevity):

```
def __init__(self, chip_version, spec_level, errata_revision,
             tpm_vendor_id, vendor_specific_data, tpm_version,
             manufacturer_info):
    self._chip_version = chip_version
    ...

@classmethod
def scan(cls):
    tpm_proc = Popen("/usr/sbin/tpm_version")
    stdout, stderr = Popen.communicate()

    tpm_dict = dict()
    for line in tpm_proc.stdout.splitlines():
        if "Version Info:" in line:
            pass
        else:
            split_line = line.split(":")
            attribute_name = (
                split_line[0].strip().replace(' ', '_').lower())
            tpm_dict[attribute_name] = split_line[1].strip()
    return cls(**tpm_dict)
```

The problem here is that this (or a different one that I may not be able to review the source of to get every possible field) could add extra things that cause my parser to work, but my object to not capture the fields.  That's what I'm really trying to solve in an elegant way.

Comment: One additional note.  Sometimes multiple commands are needed to obtain all the data, so this doesn't even necessarily get to run one command line tool to get the data it needs.

Comment: I guess I missed the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know how to do the parsing and how to write up a class to contain the data.  What I'm really looking for is "What's the best way to build an object from a parsed output in a somewhat dynamic way that can be statically analyzed?"

Comment: Can you give us a specific example? I don't see what prevents you from just using normal named arguments, because for a given command line tool you presumably know what information you're going to get out of it.

Comment: Added some example code and (what I hope is) a clarification.  Hopefully it makes sense now.  ^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on a more solid answer to this the last few months, as I basically work on hardware support libraries and have finally come up with a satisfactory (though pretty verbose) answer.

1. Parse the tool outputs, whatever they look like, into objects structures that match up to how the *tool* views the device. These can have very generic dict structures, but should be broken out as much as possible.
2. Create another container class on top of that that which uses attributes to access items in the tool-container-objects. This enforces an API and can return sane errors across multiple versions of the tool, and across differing tool outputs!